# SSH into server using kerberos service ticket that is not the host principal

Tags: openssh, kerberos

I want to ssh into a server that is running OpenSSH. My client is also OpenSSH. The server is configured to accept GSSAPI authentication, but the keytab it uses is non-standard in that the principal name is not the usual `host/myserver.example.com` (where `myserver.example.com` is the server's hostname), but instead is `service/mysql`.

My client can get a service ticket for this principal by running `kvno service/mysql`. How do I tell my ssh client to connect to `myserver.example.com` but use the `service/mysql` service ticket? Is this even possible?